# DML statements are only supported over tables that have data stored in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I am trying to use Update Set syntax to copy one column into another but its not working out. Any idea what to do here? Thankyou for replies.

> SELECT PARSE_DATE('%B %d, %Y',SaleDate)
> From `sql-practice-350112.Nashville_housing.housing_sales`
> LIMIT 1000;

> UPDATE `sql-practice-350112.Nashville_housing.housing_sales`
> SET Date_of_sale = SaleDate

I added the new column Date_of_sale from schema edit so dont have code for it.

Comment: what table what code and what is not working exactly in short please produce a [mre] in textform

Comment: Sorry if its too messy. I should have included those in the original post.

Comment: and do you get an error message?  and when  which one

Comment: you convert your date to get a date in the select, and if Date_of_sale  is a date, you should stick to the conversion  when you try to update it

Comment: To update all rows in the table, add **WHERE true** in **UPDATE** query

Comment: i got error in the update line. Error message: Invalid value: DML statements are only supported over tables that have data stored in BigQuery. Unsupported table: sql-practice-350112:Nashville_housing.housing_sales at [10:1]. Date_of_sale was not present in the original table, I added it coz I couldnt update Saledate with the parsed date. So wanted to store in another column.

Comment: I tried adding WHERE true but it says the same thing.